# Snake game -- tail movement

Tags: c++

I'm making a snake game and having trouble with the tail movement. I understand the logic for this part, which is that each segment of the tail follows the previous segment, starting from the end of the tail. I am looking at someone else's code, and it looks like this

```
 #include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <windows.h>
using namespace std;
bool gameOver;
const int width = 20;
const int height = 20;
int x, y, fruitX, fruitY, score;
int tailx[100], taily[100];
int nTail;
enum eDirecton { Stop, Left, Right, Up, Down } dir;

void Setup()
{
 gameOver = false;
 dir = Stop;
 x = width / 2;
 y = height / 2;
 fruitX = rand() % width;
 fruitY = rand() % height;
 score = 0;
}
void Draw()
{
 system("cls"); 
 for (int i = 0; i < width + 2; i++)
     cout << "#";
 cout << endl;

 for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
 {
     for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
     {
         if (j == 0)
             cout << "#";
         if (i == y && j == x)
             cout << "O";
         else if (i == fruitY && j == fruitX)
             cout << "F";
         else
         {
             bool print = false;
             for (int k = 0; k < nTail; k++)
             {
                 if (tailx[k] == j && taily[k] == i)
                 {
                     cout << "o";
                     print = true;
                 }
             }
             if (!print)
                 cout << " ";
         }


         if (j == width - 1)
             cout << "#";
     }
     cout << endl;
 }

 for (int i = 0; i < width + 2; i++)
     cout << "#";
 cout << endl;
 cout << "Score:" << score << endl;
}
void Input()
{
 if (_kbhit())
 {
     switch (_getch())
     {
     case 'a':
         dir = Left;
         break;
     case 'd':
         dir = Right;
         break;
     case 'w':
         dir = Up;
         break;
     case 's':
         dir = Down;
         break;
     case 'x':
         gameOver = true;
         break;
     }
 }
}
void Logic()
{
 for (int i = nTail - 1; i > 0; i--)
 {
     tailx[i] = tailx[i - 1];
     taily[i] = taily[i - 1];
 }
 tailx[0] = x;
 taily[0] = y;

 switch (dir)
 {
 case Left:
     x--;
     break;
 case Right:
     x++;
     break;
 case Up:
     y--;
     break;
 case Down:
     y++;
     break;
 default:
     break;
 }

 if (x >= width) x = 0; else if (x < 0) x = width - 1;
 if (y >= height) y = 0; else if (y < 0) y = height - 1;

 for (int i = 0; i < nTail; i++)
     if (tailx[i] == x && taily[i] == y)
         gameOver = true;

 if (x == fruitX && y == fruitY)
 {
     score += 10;
     fruitX = rand() % width;
     fruitY = rand() % height;
     nTail++;
 }
}
int main()
{
 Setup();
 while (!gameOver)
 {
     Draw();
     Input();
     Logic();
     Sleep(50); 
 }
 return 0;
}
```

I understand the logic but I don't understand why it works. When we create an array, the value of each element is just a garbage value without initializing each element. So in the code above, when doing

```
tailx[i] = tailx[i-1];
taily[i] = taily[i-1];
```

what value is assigned to each element? 
When displaying the snake, it has a for loop to go through every coordinate of the screen and inside it has another for loop to compare tailx[i] and taily[i] with each coordinate to find out the right position to print each segment of the tail. Since tailx and tialy are not storing the coordinates of the segments of the tail, how come this code works?

Thank you so much!!

Comment: How sure are you that it works?

Comment: Presumably, when drawing the snake, the current value of `nTail` is used, and that value is initialized or updated (when the snake gets fed food) somewhere else in the code.

Comment: The snippet you've pasted declares three variables, initializes none of them, and uses all three immediately. Are you certain that there isn't code missing from the snippet?

Comment: I am so sorry about the confusion! I've updated the post and added the whole program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presumably, you're missing a line at the end that looks something like:

```
if(nTail < 100) { nTail++; }
```

Assuming that's the case, `nTail` is initialized to 0 and that this is all in a loop, the code probably looks something like (I'm using a size of 5 instead of 100 to make visualizing easier)

```
int tailx[5];
int taily[5];
int nTail = 0; //length

while(true) {
    for(int i = nTail -1; i > 0; i--)
    {
         tailx[i] = tailx[i-1];
         taily[i] = taily[i-1];
    }

    // Let's assume there's some logic here the fetches a new
    //   x and y. For the sake of debugging, let's assume the
    //   values will be {(1, 1), (2, 2), (3, 3), (4, 4), (5, 5)}

    tailx[0] = x; // x is the x-coordinate of the head
    taily[0] = y; //y is the y-coordinate of the head
    if(nTail < 5) { nTail++; }
}
```

Let's step through this!

Before we enter the loop, your tail arrays are going to look like: (I'm using `NA` here to mean "Garbage")

```
nTail = 0

+-------------------------+
|Name | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |
|-------------------------|
|  X  | NA| NA| NA| NA| NA|
+-------------------------+
|  Y  | NA| NA| NA| NA| NA|
+-------------------------+
```

We enter the loop, initialize `i` to `nTail - 1` which is `-1`. This doesn't pass the check of `i > 0`, so we don't even enter the loop.

We'll now grab new `x` and `y` vals and assign them into the tails, along with incrementing `nTail`. So going into the next loop our variables will look like:

```
nTail = 1

+-------------------------+
|Name | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |
|-------------------------|
|  X  | 1 | NA| NA| NA| NA|
+-------------------------+
|  Y  | 1 | NA| NA| NA| NA|
+-------------------------+
```

We'll head on in, initialize `i` to `nTail - 1 => 0`. This DOESN'T pass the check of `i > 0`, so again we don't enter the loop (which sounds wrong to me...maybe you're initializing `nTail` to 1 instead of 0?).

We head on down, grab new x/y vals and increment `nTail` and restart the loop with:

```
nTail = 2

+-------------------------+
|Name | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |
|-------------------------|
|  X  | 2 | NA| NA| NA| NA|
+-------------------------+
|  Y  | 2 | NA| NA| NA| NA|
+-------------------------+
```

Initializing `i` to `nTail - 1 => 1` means since `i > 0` we'll finally enter the inner loop.

With `i = 1`, we update our tail arrays:

```
tailx[1] = tailx[0];
taily[1] = taily[0];
```

Then head down, grab new values and increment `nTail`. Our variables now look like:

```
nTail = 3

+-------------------------+
|Name | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |
|-------------------------|
|  X  | 3 | 2 | NA| NA| NA|
+-------------------------+
|  Y  | 3 | 2 | NA| NA| NA|
+-------------------------+
```

After the next loop, things will look like:

```
nTail = 4

+-------------------------+
|Name | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |
|-------------------------|
|  X  | 4 | 3 | 2 | NA| NA|
+-------------------------+
|  Y  | 4 | 3 | 2 | NA| NA|
+-------------------------+
```

I'll leave it to you to keep tracing if you so desire.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You're right; this code cannot work, and it has undefined behaviour.

`nTail` isn't even initialised to anything.

Are you sure it's a full program, and not just snippets glued together? Or a sort of "pseudocode" to show the logic without being actual valid C++? You'd need values for `nTail` and all the array elements.

Comment: I suggest a conversation with the person you got the code from.

Comment: The code is just to show the logic. In the original program, it did have nTail initialized and nTail gets updated each time the length of the snake increases.

Comment: Please don't ask us questions about code then show us some completely different code. That wastes all our time.